# Generic type for ngrx Actions in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have dynamic action:

```
export class ChangeCurrentConfig implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.ChangeCurrentConfig;

  constructor(public payload: { key: string, value: any }) {}
}
```

Where `key` is dynamic key of the reducer. For example i have:

```
interface Config1 {
  myPath1: string
}

interface Config2 {
  myPath2: string
}
```

And i load them dynamically in `CurrentConfig` reducer. And in effects of every config i handle changes for every config. For example `Config1` effect:

```
@Effect()
  changeMyPath1$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ChangeMyPath1),
    map((action: ChangeMyPath1) => action.payload.myPath1),
    map(value => {
      return new ChangeCurrentActivityConfig({
        key: 'myPath1',
        value,
      });
    })
  );
```

The problem is that there is easy to make a mistake in this line `key: 'myPath1',`. I want to prevent this with generic for `ChangeCurrentConfig` action. I tried:

```
export class ChangeCurrentConfig<T> implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.ChangeCurrentConfig;

  constructor(public payload: { key: keyof T, value: any }) {}
}
```

It works good, but i want to make this generic type **required** for new instances of the class. So if i write in effects `new ChangeCurrentActivityConfig` without generic type it will show an error. How i can achieve this?

Comment: Were you able to find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today while learning NGRX, and it was a dumb mistake on my part.  At the top I was importing `Action` from the wrong source.  I had

```
import { Action } from "rxjs/internal/scheduler/Action";
```

instead of what it should be, which is

```
import { Action } from "@ngrx/store";
```